# Advanced removal of blank rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a serious problem with a huge Excel sheet which I need to remove blank rows from.

My problem is that I cannot use the classic F5->Select blanks->delete, since some of the fields on not blank rows are also blank.

**Simplified example:**

[image]

In the above example, how would I go about deleting rows 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16 without f.x. C7 ending up in C2?

Selecting the blank rows individually would be too time consuming in the real Excel sheet, since it has over 35,000 rows, and this stunt is not a one time thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a VBA solution that will work no matter where the blanks are.  Just replace the sheet name in the code with your worksheet name, as noted in the code comments.

```
Sub delblankrows()

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim tmpR As Range
Dim rowcount As Long, colcount As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Boolean

'Change "Sheet1" to the name of your worksheet.
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tmpR = s1.UsedRange
rowcount = tmpR.Rows.Count
colcount = tmpR.Columns.Count

'Starts from bottom row and looks for non-empty cells from left to right.
'Moves to row above if non-empty cell is found.
'If none is found, then deletes row and shifts values up.
For i = rowcount To 1 Step -1
    k = 0
    For j = 1 To colcount
        If tmpR.Value2(i, j) <> "" Then
            k = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If k = 0 Then
        tmpR.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! - I had a friend look at this VBA code and it must have worked because I have a correct sheet in my hands now :)  Thanks for the other suggestions also, they would probably work just fine also.

Comment: A must learn...

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a helper column before column A in row 2 with the formula:

```
=COUNTA(B2:XFD2)
```

Copy it down 35,000 rows, autofilter column A for 0's, highlight the visible rows, and delete them.  Unfilter and the rows that had a value in at least one column will remain.  Then delete the helper column.

Comment: that's nice and clean; wish I'd said that!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

'   Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.

Dim i As Long
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

With Application
    ' Turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply find the unique column. Filter it with "Blank" value and delete all rows from excel. Then remove filter and you will get only non-blank rows

Comment: What "unique column"? Who said anything about there being a "unique column"?

Answer (score 0):

just select the whole B and C rows together, right-click and select Delete. From the options given, select "Entire column". This will get rid of the empty B and C rows and shift the D (1-3) to appear in B (1-3), just next to row A.

Comment: This will not work for the real sheet, only the simplyfied example I gave above. I will try and give a better a example that better illustrates the complexity of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed criteria for the deletion, you could write a macro to do it. Look for the columns you need deleted and delete them with (say column B):

```
columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: The requirement is to delete _rows_ and shift _up_!

Answer (score 0):

I very often use steps below to remove blank rows. You must do it before formatting cells.

- select all in Excel a sheet
- copy
- open Notepad
- paste in notepad (it will take only "clean data", without formatting)
- select all
- copy
- open Word
- paste in Word
- replace all double paragraph marks with single ones (from ^p^p to ^p)
- repeat above step until replacing all double paragraph mark occurrences
- select all
- copy
- open Excel
- paste in Excel

Comment: I don't know why Microsoft did not developed a smart solution for this recurrent work...

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table with the same layout would do it, and fast.  If you also need to preserve the original order of the rows (minus the blanks), use an additional column, which I've called "ForSort". The formula in cell D2 is =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",ROW(A2)) .  (Copy that formula all the way down column D.)

[image]

Put all the fields in the "Row Labels" section of the "Pivot Table Field List" form, as shown above.  There's no need for anything in any other section.

You can then select the entire pivot table, and copy/paste-special, values to preserve the pivot table layout.

Finally, you can do a "Replace" to get rid of the "(blank)".  And delete the "ForSort" column from the Pivot table copy if you no longer need that.